# Newbe: Dont understand description how to sync firefox

Tags: firefox, sync

want to sync firefox on two computers, both with identical ubuntu firefox. The official descrption is confusing me. I never know, which one is the "other" computer.

Where can I find a step by step introduction?

Answer (score 0):

The [Mozilla instructions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-up-firefox-sync) seem pretty simple.

Pick one computer (if they are "identical", it doesn't matter which) and set up Sync. We'll call this **computer A**. You will select "Create Account" to set up the Sync account and the Firefox information will be synced from computer A. If any other device wants to Sync that information, computer A will have to give permission for that information to be shared.

Go to any other device you have (your second computer, a phone, whatever, this will be **computer B**), except you will now select "I have an account". It will then give you a code.

In order to verify that you are giving permission for this new device to sync, you must go to computer A and put in the code ("Pair a device").

The instructions for exactly how to do this with a mobile device are slightly different but follow the same pattern, and are explained in their instructions.